# How to use EasyMockSupport through delegation with EasyMockRule or EasyMockRunner?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, easymock

Is it possible to leverage both [`EasyMockSupport`](https://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMockSupport.html) and [`EasyMockRule`](https://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMockRule.html) (or [`EasyMockRunner`](https://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMockRunner.html)) when using `EasyMockSupport` through **delegation** (instead of inheritance)?

In other words: how to make `EasyMockSupport` aware of mocks created by `EasyMockRule`?

Here is a MWE demonstrating the issue I'm facing:

```java
// Class under test
public class MyClass {
    private Collaborator collaborator;
    public MyClass() {
        collaborator = new Collaborator();
    }

    // Method under test
    public int myMethod() {
        return collaborator.mockedMethod() + 1;
    }
}

// Class to be mocked
public class Collaborator {
    public int mockedMethod() {
        return 1;
    }
}

// Test case
public class MyClassTest {
    private EasyMockSupport easyMockSupport = new EasyMockSupport();
    @Rule public EasyMockRule easyMockRule = new EasyMockRule(this);

    @TestSubject private MyClass testSubject = new MyClass();
    @Mock private Collaborator collaboratorMock;

    @Test public void testMyMethod() {
        EasyMock.expect(collaboratorMock.mockedMethod()).andReturn(2);
        easyMockSupport.replayAll();

        int result = testSubject.myMethod();
        Assert.assertEquals("Should return 2+1 when successfully mocked", 3, result);
        // throws java.lang.AssertionError: expected: <3> but was: <1>
    }
}
```

The test fails, whereas it passes if `MyClassTest` extends `EasyMockSupport`. (But I can't use inheritance for what I'm doing, hence my question.)

My comprehension of this behavior is that, in my example, `EasyMockSupport` isn't aware of the `Collaborator` mock, so calling `replayAll()` has no effect and the mock is still in record state when called in `testSubject.myMethod()` (thus `mockedMethod()` returning 0).
Indeed, [`injectMocks()` documentation](https://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMockSupport.html#injectMocks-java.lang.Object-) says:

> If the parameter extends EasyMockSupport, the mocks will be created using it to allow replayAll/verifyAll to work afterwards

But when using delegation, the parameter (i.e. the test class) doesn't extend `EasyMockSupport`. Is there something I'm missing or is it impossible?

Side note: I'm using EasyMock 3.6. Ideally I'd like to find a solution keeping that version, but feel free to indicate if there is a related feature/bugfix in a later release.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily. However it's a useful use-case so I recommend the you fill an [issue](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/issues).

Meanwhile, we need to make the rule aware of the EasyMocksSupport. Here is a solution.

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.easymock.EasyMockRule;
import org.easymock.EasyMockSupport;
import org.easymock.Mock;
import org.easymock.TestSubject;
import org.easymock.internal.MocksControl;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

// Class under test
class MyClass {
    private Collaborator collaborator;
    public MyClass() {
        collaborator = new Collaborator();
    }

    // Method under test
    public int myMethod() {
        return collaborator.mockedMethod() + 1;
    }
}

// Class to be mocked
class Collaborator {
    public int mockedMethod() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class ExtendedEasyMockSupport extends EasyMockSupport {
    public void addMock(Object mock) {
        if(EasyMockSupport.getMockedClass(mock) == null)  {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(mock + " is not a mock");
        }
        MocksControl control = MocksControl.getControl(mock);
        controls.add(control);
    }

    public void addAllMocks(Object testClass) {
        Field[] fields = testClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Mock annotation = field.getAnnotation(Mock.class);
            if(annotation != null) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object mock;
                try {
                    mock = field.get(testClass);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                addMock(mock);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Test case
public class MyClassTest {
    private final ExtendedEasyMockSupport easyMockSupport = new ExtendedEasyMockSupport();
    @Rule
    public EasyMockRule easyMockRule = new EasyMockRule(this);

    @TestSubject
    private final MyClass testSubject = new MyClass();

    @Mock
    private Collaborator collaboratorMock;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        easyMockSupport.addAllMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        EasyMock.expect(collaboratorMock.mockedMethod()).andReturn(2);
        easyMockSupport.replayAll();

        int result = testSubject.myMethod();
        Assert.assertEquals("Should return 2+1 when successfully mocked", 3, result);
        // throws java.lang.AssertionError: expected: <3> but was: <1>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll use your solution until EasyMock provides support for it. :) I filled [an issue](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/issues/258) BTW.